# Karate-Gatling: Add List of uriPatterns into karateProtocol()

Tags: karate

I have a Collection[String] of uriPatterns to include in `karateProtocol()`. Is there a way to iterate through the collection and add the `MethodPause` (in this case is Nil) without hard coding it?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you see the internal code [`PreDef.scala`](https://github.com/intuit/karate/blob/master/karate-gatling/src/main/scala/com/intuit/karate/gatling/PreDef.scala) - `karateProtocol()` is just a helper that in Scala terms - wraps `new KarateProtocol(Map[String, Seq])`.

So just build a Scala `Map` that has entries of the form `String -> Nil` and construct a `KarateProtocol`.

Comment: Thanks for the tip Peter. Solved it with something like this: 
```val urlMap = scala.collection.mutable.Map[String,Seq[MethodPause]]() for(url <- feeder){ urlMap(url) = Nil } // sort the Map to ensure {id} is the last entry val sortedUrlMap = ListMap(urlMap.toSeq.sortWith(._1 < _._1):*) val protocol = new KarateProtocol(sortedUrlMap) ```